# Why my office 2016 Home and business starts up as office 365

Tags: microsoft-office-2016

I installed office 2016 but when i start up word or excel. It put below as Office 365 as attached in image. But in file - account, it is office 2016 Home and business.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrQgA.jpg

I installed in another 2 pc but no such issues.

Comment: Look in `Programs and Features` from the **Control Panel** and look for Office 365, and then uninstall it. Reboot the machine, check now.

Comment: It sounds like this PC previously had Office 365.  Remove all Office products, reinstall Office 2016, and update your question.

Comment: I resolved a similar issue by simply uninstalling Office 365 only and then the Office 2016 issue was solved but if needed you can uninstall and re-install the Office 2016 software too after 365 is removed. I believe in that case, Office 365 was installed after and not before Office 2016 was installed, although they told me it was a mystery how that happened.... spooky.... I just fixed it as per my initial suggestion, simply uninstalling Office 365.

Comment: Its a brand new computer that i need to set up. I did went to control panel and saw there is O365, I uninstalled both )365 and O16 still cant. Reset the PC and still cannot. I think it must be some defect of some kind with the key code. Microsoft also told me that.

Comment: Try a repair install on Office 2016 then of re-install it. You might first reboot the machine after the Office 365 uninstall and then try and if there are still problems do the Office 2016 repair install or re-install. If you uninstalled Office 365 then Word 365 shouldn't be able to start.

Answer (score -1):

In Offce 2016, go to File, click on Account(Microsoft). When screen opens, see right side and click on updates. Disable future updates! No more change to Office 365.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).